# Creating a Python lambda function from a string sequence

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, function, lambda

I have a list of m  elements and n different numbers that appear in a list of strings. The list follows the following format example

```
eq = ['12', '2', '3', '-123', '-1', 'X']
```

Note, X represents the constant 1, other than the variable 1. I want to be able to convert this to a lambda function that takes in a list x and acts like this list was summed together. For our example the function would be

```
f(x) = x[1]*x[2] + x[2] + x[3] - x[1]*x[2]*x[3] - x[1] + 1
```

I know how to do this with a normal function, but I wanted to get it to work with a lambda and hit a wall. Any help would be appreciated!

Here is the function that works for the problem:

```
def evaluateList(x, lst):
    num = 0
    for term in lst:
        if term[0] == "X":
            num += 1
        elif term[0] == "-":
            num -= reduce(lambda x,y: x*y, [x[int(y)-1] for y in term[1:]])
        else:
            num += reduce(lambda x,y: x*y, [x[int(y)-1] for y in term])
    return num
```

Comment: Can you show the function definition that works for your problem?

Comment: @Carcigenicate unless there's state involved, which depending on implementation there could be

Comment: @BowlingHawk95 I just added the working function implementation. Thank you for the advice

Comment: @wjmccann the reason you're having trouble is (as mentioned above), you can't have state in lambda's.  Because `num` is changing value over iterations, that implementation won't work in a lambda.  But all is not lost! Any stateful iterative algorithm can be translated to a stateless one using combinators like `map`, `reduce`, and `filter`.  This algorithm will look quite different than your function above, but it is doable.  Let me play with it and see what I can come up with.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `functools.reduce` twice, although the result is not very clean:

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import sub, add
eq = ['12', '2', '3', '-123', '-1', 'X']
_x = [6, 4, 1, 4, 5, 2, 4, 23, 2, 4]
final_result = reduce(lambda x, y:[add, sub][y.startswith('-')](
  reduce(lambda c, d:c*d, [_x[int(i)] for i in x]) if x in eq else x, 
  reduce(lambda c, d:c*d, [_x[int(i)] for i in (y[1:] if y.startswith('-') else y)] if y != 'X' else [1])
  ), eq)
```

---

```
print(final_result)
x = _x
print(x[1]*x[2] + x[2] + x[3] - x[1]*x[2]*x[3] - x[1] + 1)
```

Output:

```
-10
-10
```

But again, a predefined function is much easier to read and scale.

Also, slightly shorter, with `sum`:

```
new_result = sum([1, -1][i.startswith('-')]*reduce(lambda x, y:x*y, [1] if i == 'X' else [x[int(c)] for c in (i[1:] if i.startswith('-') else i)]) for i in eq)
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this is simple enough:

```
from operator import mul
from functools import reduce
prod = lambda L: reduce(mul, L, 1)
evaluateList = lambda(x, eq): sum(
    1 if expr == 'X' 
    else prod(-1 if i == '-' 
              else x[int(i)] 
              for i in expr) 
    for expr in eq)
```

Comment: Really wish `functools.reduce` used kwargs so you could simplify the `prod` assignment with `functools.partial`.

Answer (score 3):

Clearly I recommend the `def` implementation:

```
from functools import reduce

eq = ['12', '2', '3', '-123', '-1', 'X']
x = [n for n in range(100)]

# Using an auxiliary function
def evaluate(n):
    if n == "X":
        return 1
    elif n[0] == "-":
        return reduce(lambda x, y: x * y, [x[int(y) - 1] for y in n[1:]])
    else:
        return reduce(lambda x, y: x * y, [x[int(y) - 1] for y in n])

print(sum(map(evaluate, eq)))

# As a pure lambda:

evaluate_lambda = lambda n: sum(map((lambda n: 1 if n == 'X' else (reduce(lambda x, y: x * y, [x[int(y) - 1] for y in n[1:]]) if n[0] == "-" else reduce(lambda x, y: x * y, [x[int(y) - 1] for y in n]))), eq))

print(evaluate_lambda(eq))
```

Answer (score 2):

that's a bit ugly but it works

```
from operator import mul
a = lambda eq: sum([reduce(mul, [int(x) if x.isdigit() else [1,-1][x=='-'] for x in s]) for s in eq])


print(a(['12', '2', '3', '-123', '-1', 'X']))  # outputs 1
print(a(['126', '32', '3', '-2', 'X']))  # outputs 20
```

edit: of course this is just a game. always use the most **readable** function

Comment: `[1,-1][x=='-']` relies on the python quirk that True is secretly 1 and False is zero.  That's really really hard to debug when buried in a large module IMO.   Would avoid this if at all possible.

Comment: of course. but the whole lambda-ing that function is a game. so let's have fun